# Parameters to be passed to the CreateDIBSection function

Tags: c, image, winapi, bitmap

I have a color image with number of rows 479 and columns 638. I am trying to save this image as a BMP file. For this I am first using `CreateDIBSection` and then using `CreateDIBitmap`. For the `CreateDIBSection` I need to pass the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` to the function. Here it has two parameters `biWidth` and `biSizeImage`. Since the memory returned by the function should be DWORD aligned, and `638` is not a multiple of `4` should I pass 638 or 640 as the width ? Assume that I pass 638 as the width, will the memory returned by the function be 638 x 479 or 640 x 479 ? My observation is that it is the 640 x 479. In this case when I save the file as a BMP a 2 pixel wide black line appears at the end of each row. How do I avoid this? I am passing `biCompression` as `BI_RGB` if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the actual width as the bitmap width. The scanline/stride however has to be dword aligned. This just means adding up to 3 bytes to each line when calculating the stride and memory buffer size.

Note that the actual width of the data depends on the bits per pixel. If you;re using 32-bit pixels then it's already aligned correctly.